# create new channel and join peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have few basic doubts regarding creating a channel in fabric. I was trying to set up the first network with individual commands.
I came across multiple commands for creating channel but unable to understand the difference

a. `sudo docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/configtx/composer-channel.tx — tls true — cafile /etc/configtx/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem`

b. `peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel1 -f ./channel-artifacts/channel1.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA`

1. Does channel need to be created under an orderer container or peer container?
2. in the above command I can see peer0.org1.example.com with exec, is it given to create the channel inside the peer container?
3. In the command b peer0.org1.example.com is not given, is it because we run this command inside CLI?

I just wanted to understand how to works with the channel creation syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I can see why this can be confusing.  At a high level:

1. In order to create a channel, you need to submit a configuration
   transaction to an orderer node (aka "create channel").
2. In order for peers to receive blocks from a channel and to invoke
   chaincode on a channel, you need to call the "join channel API" on
   each peer.

The confusing part is that there is only a single CLI (command-line interface) for performing both actions and it is actually the `peer` executable.

So when you call `peer channel create ...` you are actually sending a configuration transaction to an ordering node.

You can either execute the `peer ...`  commands inside a container which has the peer executable ( that's the `docker exec ...` you show above ) or you can run the `peer` binary on a host system and do the same thing (the second option you show above runs it within the CLI container).

Comment: so basically 1st command is to achieve the same result without CLI ? is it so?

Comment: first command executes the CLI inside the peer container via `docker exec`

Comment: so how to create the channel then if we don't have CLI container? as i read that CLI is not mandatory to have

Comment: Hyperledger Fabric also exposes these operations through SDKs available for Javascript, Java, Go and Python. You could then write your own application that utilizes these operations.